# How do I find out something is a struct(value type) or a class(reference type) in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, types, struct

I am using someone's SDK, but the document does not tell me something is a struct or a class.

How can I find out that? `typeof` or `GetType` just show the name.

I'd like find out that in the IDE(VS2010); approaches through coding are also acceptable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Programmatically speaking, you can use `GetType().IsValueType`.

From Visual Studio, you can also check by using the *Object Browser* (shown below, found under View -> Object Browser).

[image: object browser]

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned, you can find out whether a generic type is a class type or value type by calling `IsValueType` on the type object.  Note, however, that it's not meaningful to test whether an object *instance* is a value type.  Although C# will pretend that a reference-type fields can hold a value-type instance, that's an illusion.  For every value type there is a corresponding class type with the same name and fields.  Calling `GetType().IsValueType` on a storage location holding a reference to such an instance will report true, even though the storage location in fact holds a reference to a class object.  This can be demonstrated readily with structs that implement mutating interfaces (e.g. `List<string>.Enumerator`, which I'll call `LSE` for short).

An `LSE` which is stored in a variable of type `LSE` will behave as a value type.  Copying an `LSE` which is about to return the third item of a list to another variable of type `LSE` will yield a second, *independent* enumerator, which is also about to return the third item.  One can read items from either enumerator without affecting the other.  By contrast, if one has a variable of type `IEnumerable<string>` which holds a reference to an `LSE`, and one copies that to another variable of type `IEnumerable<string>`, one will have a second reference to *the same* enumerator.  Reading items from one enumerator will also advance the other.  In other words, copying an `LSE` to a reference-type storage location will yield something which will behave like a reference type because, under the covers, it will actually be one.

Note that calling `GetType` on a storage location won't reveal whether it holds a real value type, or whether it holds an object of the class associated with a value type.  In the former case, the system will create a new instance of the class associated with the value type and call `GetType` on that, so in both cases the `GetType` call will actually be processed on a class-type instance.

Comment: What you're describing is the effect of boxing value types. A struct is always a value type, but if it is boxed, then yes, you have a reference to the boxed copy. You seem to describe this as a "object of the class associated with the value type" and a "real value type" are two different things, but they're not. An "instance" of System.Int32 is always a value type, but yes, it may be boxed.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: If one passes a value of type `List<string>.Enumerator` to a routine as parameter type `IEnumerable<string>`, the result will behave as a class type.  The CLS specification (which details the environment in which typical C# implementations are run) describes things in essentially the terms I described.  C# may pretend that boxed value types are still value types, but since the CLS spec says that "under the covers" they're really not, and since they behave like class types rather than value types, I don't see how the C# definition is helpful.

Comment: It will behave as a reference type because you have boxed it, it is still a value type though. You can box a value type to give it *some* of the behavior of reference types, but not all of them, and a value type never transitions to becoming a reference type.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Consider the following questions: "When will copying an instance of a type which implements `IEnumerable<string>` to a variable of type `IEnumerable<string>` create a new instance, and when will it simply copy a reference to an existing instance?", and "Can an `Integer` be passed as a generic-typed parameter with a `class` constraint?"  If one recognizes boxed value types as actually being class objects, the answers to the above questions are simple: class-type objects exhibit reference behavior; value-type storage locations exhibit value-type behavior.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: If I pass a method a parameter of type `IEnumerable<string>`, is there any means whatsoever that it could determine whether it was a value type or class type without Reflection?  The CLS spec says that such a thing will be internally processed as a class type (whether it's a standalone class, or the namesake class associated with a value type), and the thing will have behavior indistinguishable from a class type.  If it's a class type internally, and it behaves like one, in what way would it be helpful to regard it as anything else?